# How to type speech input into wherever the text cursor is? (dictation mode)

Tags: c#, winforms

I am building a speech recognition program that can switch from 'command' mode to 'dictation' mode and vice versa.

What i am trying to achieve is a way for the program to type whatever the user says **wherever the text cursor is**.
Like when i open gmail and compose a new message, i want to be able to write in the zone where i clicked.

Basically i already have the speech input converted into text and it shows whatever i say in my TextContent which is the area of my windows form that contains the text.

```
private void _recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e) // speech event handler
{
     string speech = e.Result.Text.ToString(); // converts the speech input into text.
     txtContents.Text += speech + Environment.NewLine; //writes the text that gets recognized by speech engine into the windows form text area.
}
```

So all i need is a way to type wherever the "text cursor" is. (outside of my program)
e.g. If i have a notebook file open i want to write in there, if i click on the adress bar on firefox I want to type in there etc.

It's one of my first project in visual studio, I'm actually not used to program anything else than games in unity so be indulgent if the answer is obvious.

Also if there was already another thread with the same question, I'm sorry but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question was just to use `SendKeys.Send`..